# How to convert video and output to BytesIO without saving?

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, ffmpy

Using ffmpy to convert video(or gif image) that uploaded. I want to convert the file without saving (i.e. input is a BytesIO, and output with a BytesIO). How can I do that?

Comment: If you solved this, how did you do it?